# How to fix undeclared fonts?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, cyrillic, times

I've wasted several days in attempts to setup the cyrillic Times New Roman in my document. I will be happy to use XeLaTeX, but the class **disser** I need does not support it (even when I removed the hardcoded hypertex driver, the hyperref configuration was totally broken after XeLaTeX).

Now I try to use the following configuration

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}

\usepackage{newtxtext}  % Times for numbers in math mode

\usepackage{newtxmath}  % Times in math mode

\usepackage{pscyr}  % Cyrillic Times New Roman for text, not in CTAN
\renewcommand\rmdefault{ftm}

\begin{document}

    Привет

    1234567890

    $1234567890$

\end{document}
```

and I get annoying warnings

```
Font shape `T2A/ntxtlf/m/n' undefined(Font) using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead
Font shape `T1/ftm/m/n' undefined(Font) using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead
Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

If I remove at least one of these blocks, I will get this ugly Computer Modern in some place.

I have the following questions:

1. Why does it even need the T1 encoding?? I have no text that uses it.
2. Why does it searches for T2A/ntxtlf if I explicitly set the **ftm** font?
3. Where will I see the **cmr** font?
4. How to avoid this warnings?

Comment: We need links to help you: at least to know where `pscyr` is to be found and preferably where `disser.cls` can be found, too. (But the latter is less essential as we can just stick to the MWE.)

Comment: Do `\usepackage{tempora}` instead of `\usepackage{newtxtext}`. Remove `\usepackage{pscyr}` and also the `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm}`.

Comment: [pscyr](http://tex.imm.uran.ru/texserver/fonts/pscyr/pscyr4c/), 
[disser](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/disser). But these packages are fully OK. The problec is caused by newtx. If I change it to mathptmx, the warnings will disappear

Comment: What is you distribution? I've just downloaded `pscyr`and installed it fairly easily, albeit I don't speak Russian.

Comment: again, pscyr is totally OK. There's no problems with it. `newtx` package causes these warnings. I use MikTeX on Windows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The more recent TeX distributions provide a Times-like font that supports the Cyrillic and Greek alphabets, loaded through the package `tempora`.

```
\documentclass{disser}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}

\usepackage{tempora}  % Times for numbers in math mode
\usepackage{newtxmath}  % Times in math mode

\begin{document}

Привет

1234567890

$1234567890$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's really a good news. Thank you, I didn't know

Comment: @Himura Thanks to Michael Sharpe! His job with fonts in invaluable.

Comment: I stil have warnings (( 
`Font shape 'T1/cmss/m/n' in size <10.5> not available(Font) size <10.95> substituted`, `Font shape 'T1/cmtt/m/n' in size <10.5> not available(Font) size <10.95> substituted`, 
`Size substitutions with differences(Font) up to 0.45pt have occurred.`

Comment: @Himura Add `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` before `\documentclass`

Comment: It works. But I need to search what this line does... Thank you

Comment: @Himura Traditionally, fonts were available only at a fixed set of sizes (they were bitmap); the `fix-cm` package makes the Computer Modern font family arbitrary scalable, taking advantage of modern font technology.

Comment: I see. I wish I could also change the tt font to something less overloaded and wide, but it's not so important, thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

1. `T1` is required by `newtxtext.sty`:

   ```
   \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
   ```

You have requested `english` as a secondary language. `T1` will be used for English, with American hyphenation patterns. It may also be used for some letters in maths, but I did not check to see if this is the case or not. `OT1` is default, but `newtxmath.sty` may substitute `T1`, as some packages do.

2. When a font encoding is configured, a default fall back font is configured for that specific encoding. This is different from setting `\rmdefault` because you that family might not support the relevant encoding. This sets the font which is fallen back to for that specific encoding, if all else fails.

`cmr` is not ugly. I agree that it does not work well with Times clones, but that is not at all the same thing.

Comment: OK, now I see I need T1. I didn't know it serves latin letters. But in my document English is not in `cmr`, but in Times. Does it substitude as it says?

Comment: @Himura Probably not, but I'm not sure. Some definitions are deferred, so it might substitute but then that substitute gets overridden later, before you typeset anything. Just remove the `\renewcommand` - it isn't going to do you any good and just confuses things. You can tell what fonts are loaded by looking at the console/log to see if something is later loaded to replace it. `newtxtext.sty` depends on redefining `\rmdefault`, for that aspect of its typesetting, except when Babel is used, when it does something else. So probably the something else is effective here.